# Undefined index errors when using plus equal operator

Tags: php

I'm working on another developers old code and there are tons of Notice: Undefined index errors when data is being set using the += operator. Essentially the index is not set yet in the array so the error is generated.

Example:

```
$myArray = array();
$myValue = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    $myArray['test'] += 1;
}
```

Will generate an error on the first run since the test index is not set yet.

I know I can remove this error with the following code:

```
$myArray = array();
$myValue = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    if ( ! isset($myArray['test']) )
    {
        $myArray['test'] = $myValue;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $myArray['test'] += $myValue;
    }
}
```

However, there are around 50 of things like this to change. Is it worth writing all these isset statements or is there a better way I am not aware of?

EDIT: I should note that the array indexes aren't always the same and sometimes aren't set so I can't preset the index in this circumstance to avoid the error.

Comment: Is it an option for you to just turn off PHP Notices?

Comment: All errors are off on the production server. I just noticed these errors after having to edit something on my development server. Would it be OK to ignore these then?

Comment: `array_key_exists` + `isset` if you want to do it the real hardcore way ;)

Comment: I would try to get away from them. If you avoid them in general, the ones you get (unexpectedly) are quite helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit shorter, but perhaps still a bit complicated if you have many edits.

```
$myArray = array();
$myValue = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    isset($myArray['test']) ? $myArray['test'] += $myValue : $myArray['test'] = $myValue;

}
```

You could also write a global function (not tested)..

```
$myArray = array();   
$myValue = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    increment($myArray['test'], $myValue);
}

function increment(&$var, $inc){
    $var = isset($var) ? $var += $inc : $var = $inc
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP 7 and above, you can use [the Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) to make this code cleaner.

```
$myArray = [];
$myValue = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    $myArray['test'] = $myValue + ($myArray['test'] ?? 0);
}
```

The benefit here is not only that the code is cleaner, but you're also being more explicit about the default value (`0`)

Answer (score 0):

Old/Deprecaded/Unrecommended but the shortest solution is

```
@$myArray['test'] += $myValue;
```

Comment: Is this black magic? It still works as of 2021

Comment: Don't do this! (WOLFF did say "Unrecommended".) If someone comes along and replaces $myValue with myFunc() and that function errors, this will gobble up the error. Very bad practice!

Comment: @thedude12 YES :D

Comment: @thedude12 It doesn't "work", it just hides the error. Then a few years later, an unknown unknown happens, and that line of code causes a fatal error, the software doesn't work anymore, and nothing shows in the logs. Then you spend a lot of hours until eventually you find the culprit. Moral of the story, don't use error suppression.

Comment: still working in 2022 in php 8.1, if You are creating some aside script and You want to do it fast, You can use this then.